# How to display multiple table from signle query on webpage using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hi there i am new to php i want to show multiple table records on webpage using single query so how can i do that please help me if anyone know
any help would be appreciated.
thanks..!!

i have table in database like this

```
Name  |  Dept        |        Desg<br />
abc   |  sales       |      executive<br />
xyz   |  account     |      executive<br />
pqr   |  marketing   |      executive<br />
lmo   |  sales       |      executive<br />
kuv   |  marketing   |      executive<br />
xtx   |  account     |      executive<br />
aaa   |  sales       |      executive<br />
```

i want result like this create each table dynamically based on respective Dept

```
Name |   Dept      |          Desg<br />
abc  |   sales     |        executive<br />
lmo  |   sales     |        executive<br />
aaa  |   sales     |        executive

Name  |  Dept         |       Desg<br />
pqr   |  marketing    |     executive<br />
kuv   |  marketing    |     executive

Name  |  Dept         |       Desg<br />
xyz   |  account      |     executive<br />
xtx   |  account      |     executive
```

Comment: Can you use order by Dept DESC in your mysql query ?

Comment: I don't see any MySQL or PHP here. What have you tried?

Comment: yes i have tried but not succeed

Comment: how can i write php code to achieve above result? Dharman

Comment: @prakash If you want to ping someone, you need to prepend their name with @

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try like this. Suppose that you already query all the table in one query using something like `SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ....` and put it into `$query_results`

```
    $tables = [];
    foreach($query_results as $result) {
        if ( ! isset($tables[$result->dept])) {
            $tables[$result->dept] = [];
        }
        $tables[$result->dept][] = $result;
    }
```

And that to show the table, the code should be look like this

```
    foreach($tables as $table_name => $data_group) {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<thead><th>Name</th> <th>Dept</th> <th>Desg</th> </thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";
        foreach($data_group as $row) {
            echo "<td>" . $row->name . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->dept . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row->desg . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but when i applied it i am getting following notice on my php page "Notice: Trying to get property 'dept' of non-object" so how i am gonna resolve it?

Comment: Well it depend on your data structure when you fetch the data.

Comment: Prakash is probably getting the results as associative array which is why it doesn't work for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below php code for for getting the result as given in your requirement

```
$resultArr = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `emp` WHERE 1 order by name ASC, dept desc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$indx = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $dept = $row["dept"];
        $resultArr[$dept][$indx] = $row ; // Group values to department array
        $indx++;

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

foreach($resultArr as $key => $depts){

    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Name</th><th>Dept</th><th>Desg</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach($depts as $values){

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$values['name'].'</td><td>'.$values['dept'].'</td><td>'.$values['desig'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

I have used the database schema as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `emp` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `dept` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `desig` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```